# Does California require smoke detectors in a garage used as a laundry room?

Tags: rental-property, landlord, safety

The building I live in is a 4 unit apartment that used to be one large single family residence. The garage is located under my unit, next to one unit on the ground floor. There is a door from the garage to the ground floor unit. Today my wife called while i was at work and told me she smelled smoke when she went into the garage. Our neighbor determined (unsure how) that the problem was our laundry dryer. He unplugged the machine. My wife called the landlord and they said they would come take a look some time later this week (it is Monday). The garage has no smoke detector. This has me worried, as a fire that started in the garage could get quite large before we were alerted to its presence in our upstairs unit, and our stairs go down a wall shared by the garage. The only thing I can find about california fire code on smoke detectors is that they have to be located inside and just outside of all sleeping areas. Is my landlord required to install a smoke detector in the garage/laundry room? If not is there anything else I can do other than ask the landlord to install a smoke detector? This landlord is historically incredibly cheap and loath to do anything to help their tenants.

Comment: You could install one yourself - a battery powered smoke detector can be bought for under $15 and doesn't require any wiring.  The landlord might remove it, of course, but if he's that lazy he may not notice or bother.

Comment: Though according to https://www.usfa.fema.gov/prevention/outreach/garage_fires.html you probably want a "heat alarm" instead of a smoke detector.  But that part of the question is probably more for http://diy.stackexchange.com than here.